# How to add custom field to buddypress profile?

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

How can I add custom fields to buddypress profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend this class to add custom profile fields: `BP_XProfile_Field_Type`

```
class Your_Field_Type_Name extends BP_XProfile_Field_Type { //etc
```

You'll find the class in `buddypress\bp-xprofile\classes\`